# How to migrate from TFS 2018.2 on-premise to DevOps server

Tags: tfs, collections, migration, devops, team-project-collection

im wondering about migrate from on-premise TFS 2018.2 to on-premise DevOps Server but cant find any tool for migrating tfs collection to on-premise server.

Did any one of you have any suggestion?

Comment: Please describe what you have tried as of now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevOps Server 2019 is just a rename for TFS.

First make sure you backup your VM (if a VM) or/and the TFS databases.

You can just uninstall TFS 2018.2 (leave the database there) then install Azure DevOps server 2019 and select the upgrade path and it will upgrade in-place.

you have some information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/get-started?view=azure-devops
and here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/upgrade/walkthrough?view=azure-devops

Good luck